# Change in textfield and "save before quit"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

i'm trying to add a "save before quit" alert on my app to avoid data loss if the user want to go back without saving on the previous view.
I know there's a lot of method, but why this doesn't seems to work?

1) declare this two variables:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isChanged;
```

2)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *modifiedText;
```

3) set to false "isChanged" at the init

4)

```
  (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  self.modifiedText = textField.text;
```

5)

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 if(![self.modifiedText isEqualToString:textField.text]){
        self.isChanged = YES;
 }
 else{
        self.isChanged = NO;
  }
```

But i've a exc_bad_access on modified text on 5. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Change your property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *modifiedText;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *modifiedText;
```

[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662772/nsstring-no-assign-retain-or-copy-attribute-is-specified)

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare **modifiedText** property this way:

```
@property (copy) NSString *modifiedText;
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/387959/2298998) question for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *modifiedText;
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *modifiedText;
```

Instead of assign.