# ARC gives warning if I remove strong life time qualifier from property, it should not because Under ARC, strong is the default for object types

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have converted non-ARC project into ARC, but XCode5.0 is giving below warning for line

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *latitude;
```

**Warning: No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed**

When I add strong life time qualifier then Warning goes out.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *latitude;
```

Under ARC, strong is the default for object types, so why XCode is giving warning if I dont mention its a strong property?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662772/nsstring-no-assign-retain-or-copy-attribute-is-specified

Comment: Thanks..Yes I know this is abovious error in non-ARC project. As I mentioned I am getting this error after enabling ARC and converting non-arc project into ARC.

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning. If I add strong then error goes out.

Comment: Check Objective C Automatic Reference Counting flag in build settings of your project is Yes or No. I think your project is not converted to ARC properly.

Comment: Yes Checked Flag is set to YES, Its running properly without crashing..first I enabled ARC in project setting and then converted project into ARC using option provided using XCode(Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC). Also did some changes manually at some places for ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Did you through "Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC" to enable ARC? Or just change project setting? You can try first method to convert project to ARC.

Comment: Thanks..But Yes first I enabled ARC in project setting and then converted project into ARC using option provided using XCode(Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC). Also did some changes manually at some places for ARC.